# JQuery: showing elements with a particular title

Tags: jquery, compare, attributes

I am trying to show only elements that have the title attribute passed to the function:

```
var selectservice = function(serviceStr) {
    $j("li.project").hide();
    $j("li.project.attr('title').contains(serviceStr)").show();
};
```

I am not quite sure how to compare the title attribute to the passed string serviceStr? contains doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), like this:

```
var selectservice = function(serviceStr) {
    $j("li.project").hide();
    $j("li.project[title='" + serviceStr + "']").show();
};
```

Note that there are other options for attributes as well, not just equals, like contains, ends with, starts with, etc.  [See here for a full list](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).